# How to properly get object data via Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get object data using Reactjs from my Atlassian Instance.

When I run the code, the `{JSON.stringify(data)}` shows the record as per below:

```
{"creator_name":"Nancy More","current_time":"10/21/2023, 12:37:11 PM"}
```

Now am trying to display **creator_name** if the object record is not empty as this line of code:

```
{JSON.stringify(data) !=='{}'   &&  <span> Welcome {data.creator_name}</span> <input type='text' value={data.creator_name} /> }
```

But it keeps throwing error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: d is null
    Vf App.js:
```

Here is the code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";

function App() {


  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
invoke('getdata-creator_name').then(setData);
}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Display Records creators name</h2>
       

{JSON.stringify(data) === '{}' && Record is empty}

 
{JSON.stringify(data) !=='{}'   &&  <span> Welcome {data.creator_name}</span> <input type='text' value={data.creator_name} /> }


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import Resolver from '@forge/resolver';
const resolver = new Resolver();

resolver.define('getdata-creator_name', async (req) => { 
const datax = await storage.get('my-key');
console.log(datax);
return datax;

});

export const handler = resolver.getDefinitions();
```

Comment: Initilize data with {} i.e  `const [data, setData] = useState({})` ;rather than null, if you are expecting the result as you want.Since initial value is null, you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like stringyfying the data doesn't make sense...

you can render the object property when it exists like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";

function App() {


  const [data, setData] = useState({}); // initialize to empty object

  useEffect(() => {
invoke('getdata-creator_name').then(setData);
}, []);
const {creator_name} = data // destructure data

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Display Records creators name</h2>
       

           {!creator_name && Record is empty}

 
            {!!creator_name  &&<span> Welcome {creator_name}</span> <input type='text' value={creator_name} /> }


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```